# Extract all noon data from a timeseries

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on hourly electric load data which has 8760 points for the entire year
It looks like this

```
Date                ...
2017-01-01 00:00:00 ...
2017-01-01 01:00:00 ...
2017-01-01 02:00:00 ...
2017-01-01 03:00:00 ...
2017-01-01 04:00:00 ...
```

My goal is to get all the noon data(values at 12:00 for every day of the year) in a separate dataframe.

I tried df.groupby(df.index.hour) but it aggregates the data for every hour

Any help on this would be great.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.
However, if you follow whatever resources you find on line, make an honest coding attempt, and run into a problem, you'd have a good example to post.

Comment: Sure, would keep that in mind. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

***Setup***

```
dr = pd.date_range(start='2018-01-01', periods=48, freq='1H')
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(Date=dr))
```

---

You can use the `dt` selector here:

```
df[df.Date.dt.hour.eq(12)]
```

```
                  Date
12 2018-01-01 12:00:00
36 2018-01-02 12:00:00
```

If you actually have a `DateTimeIndex`, you can follow the same pattern:

```
df[df.index.hour==12]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
import datetime

df[df['hour']==datetime.time(12,0)]
```

From what you have tried, I assume you have a column named hour.

Comment: Yes I do. Tried it. Shows invalid type comparison

Comment: what is the datatype of hour column? Cast the string to the same datatype.

Comment: Got it. Was comparing the hour to a string but df['Date'].dt.hour returns an int64 value

Comment: @Chinmay see edit